# F# Creating a delegate with void return

Tags: delegates, f#

I am trying to write a f-sharp program which should use a C#/.Net dll. The C# code looks like this:

```cs
public delegate void OnX (X x);
public delegate void OnXError (X x, string error);
public Foo(OnX onX, OnXError onXError);
```

My current try in F# Llooks like this:

```
let OnX (x:X) =
   ()
let OnXError (x:X) (error:sting)=
   ()
let foo=new Foo(OnX,OnXError)
```

This does not compile. OnX has type x -> unit instead of OnX.  I have also tried to create the delegate in a seperate binding, but have not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the delegate explicitly:

```
let d1 = new OnX(fun (x: X) -> ())
let d2 = new OnXError(fun (x: X) (error: string) -> ())
```

Comment: Is The OnX now the C# function or the F# version? I get OnX not defined.

Comment: @weismat - `OnX` is the C# delegate. You will need to fully qualify the name or open the namespace to find the definition.

Comment: I realized this after checking the defintion again. Thanks a lot